# Specifying a fixed parameter with mle2 (bbmle)

Tags: mle

Specifying a fixed parameter when using mle2 leads to an error. This occurs when I specify the likelihood with a formula.

```
library(ggplot2)
mle2(carat ~ dnorm(mean = a * x + b, sd = 1), start = list(a = 1), fixed = list(b = 1), data = diamonds)

Error in mle2(carat ~ dnorm(mean = a * x + b, sd = 1), start = list(a = 1),  : 
  some named arguments in 'fixed' are not arguments to the specified log-likelihood function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve the error by including 'b=1' in the specification of the starting guesses, e.g.:

```
mle2(carat ~ dnorm(mean = a * x + b, sd = 1), start = list(a = 1, b = 1), fixed = list(b = 1), data = diamonds)
```

Even though 'b' is listed in the starting guesses, because it is also specified in the list of fixed parameters, mle2 will not tinker with its value.